# iOS: How to perform function periodically

Tags: ios, swift

I need to have a function called once a week to reset user progress. The function should be called every week once on a set day, if the user opens the app on that day. If the app was not opened (and thus the function was not called) on the set day that week, the function should then be called the next time the app is opened.

How would one go about doing that in Swift?

Comment: save the date of the last update and check if a new update is needed when the [app transitions from the background to the active state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623076-applicationwillenterforeground)

Comment: Either you have a connection to a server already existing, and I would do that from there, by calling the server on startup to know if the progress should be reset. 
Or if you don't have a server, As Daniel suggested, I would save on the device the date of the last change requested (not the current date, when the user open the app) and on start up look if that date is more than a week old.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple method. First store the `Date()` to `UserDefaults` the last time method was performed. Then check if the method was performed within the last week, if not perform the method and replace the stored `Date` with the new current `Date()`.

Update: This assumes that the task should be performed periodically seven days after the date task was performed previously, it doesn't consider a particular weekday for example if you want the task to be performed on the next Sunday even if the task was previously performed on Saturday of the previous week you could just store the first weekday instead of storing the current date.

Comment: Problem with storing the current Date you can "drift" from the update date. 
Let's say the update is on Monday if the user open the app on Wednesday, the week after the update will only be available from Wednesday.

Comment: You have to store the Date of the last requested update.

Comment: In that case, you could store the first-week day date instead of the current date. Although this is not specified in the OP.

Comment: "The function should be called every week once on a set day" :)

Comment: Thanks. How would you deal with different months having different number of days when comparing the saved date with the current date to determine if a week has passed?

Comment: @DanielŠlechta Checking if the week has passed has no effect on the end of month or year. You should know that a week is always 7 days, irrespective of month or year.

Comment: That's a different question. But Date don't necessarily cares about the day number, you can check for a time difference of 7 days

Comment: @Frankenstein Sure. My point was about the reset happening on the same day of the week. I will try the what was added by La pieuvre in the update. Thanks.